# How to create a null model for conditional logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I would like to see if including some covariates will give me an AIC which is smaller than the null model, while working with conditional logistic regression in R (discrete choice).

I realize I can build a model, such as

```
mymodel <- clogit(choice ~ dark+soft+nuts + strata(ID), data=candy)
```

and get the AIC by using

```
extractAIC(mymodel)[2]
```

But I am a little unsure as to how I can create a null model to compare this against. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fit a model without covariates

```
nullmodel <- clogit(choice ~ 1 + strata(ID), data=candy)
```

That's assuming that your null is that `dark+soft+nuts` have no effect on choice. Otherwise be clear about what your null and alternative hypothesis are.

Comment: This crashes my R session for some reason, but that's my problem, and I get the point.  Thanks!

Comment: why is strata(ID) included in the formula? it should be excluded for the null model?