# Creating a null model in clogit in R

Tags: r, null, crash

Every time I try to create a null model for my conditional logistic regression, R crashes.

Here is a post by Matt O'Brian who also had this problem but did not ever note how it was fixed:
[How to create a null model for conditional logistic regression in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225451/how-to-create-a-null-model-for-conditional-logistic-regression-in-r)

Any suggestions? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you shouldn't be able to create a null model. Old versions of either R or the survival package allowed you to do this, but they were invalid.